# How can i install dspace 7 (restAPI and angular)?

Tags: dspace

How can i install dspace 7 (restAPI and angular) like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKnos2jTdSQ?.
I have installed front-end (https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular). Back-end, I searched RestAPI (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace-spring-rest) and deloyed in Tomcat9 but false. Thanks!

Comment: can you add some details to your question? do you have issues in installing the software or are you seeing missing features? if the latest, please note that the youtube video was based on the or2018-demo branches that includes features not yet merged in the master. https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular/tree/or2018
https://github.com/4Science/DSpace/tree/or2018-demo We are working hard to improve and finalize these features

Comment: Can you give me guide step by step to install dspace 7 (or a document or a link)? Thank you!

Comment: An easy way to give DSpace 7 (Backend & Frontend) a try is to use [tag:docker].
Follow the instructions on 1. [DSpace-Docker-Images](https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images)
2. [Running DSpace with Docker compose](https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images/blob/master/docker-compose-files/dspace-compose/README.md)
3. [Running DSpace 7](https://github.com/DSpace-Labs/DSpace-Docker-Images/blob/master/documentation/run.DSpace7.md) There is also a video and slide-set from a recent (3/2019) webinar explaining the process: [DuraSpace Webinar: DSpace Docker for Repository Manager

Comment: Hi, I followed those steps, I get every docker image running, but when I get to localhost:3000 it has an infinite "loading" gif, toggling the web developer tools in Firefox, It says "Cross Origin Request Blocked" because "CORS headers is missing". I already had this message in angular apps, but I can't access the code, can I? How can I fix this? The problem is that the code allowing the frontend localhost:3000 accessing the backend localhost:8080 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

DSpace 7 is not yet released. We do not yet have a step-by-step install guide for DSpace 7, as that will come as part of the release process. See DSpace 7 Release Plans at https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/DSpace+Release+7.0+Status

Currently there are separate setup guides for the DSpace 7 REST API and Angular UI.

- REST API (backend) can be installed using the normal DSpace installation process (same as in DSpace 6.x and below). The rough notes are at https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC7x/Installing+DSpace
- Angular UI (frontend) must be installed separately using the instructions in the README: https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular/blob/master/README.md

Again, as DSpace 7 is not yet released, the above links only provide **early documentation**. They are also currently very developer oriented (as development is still ongoing, and therefore only developers are installing DSpace 7).

If you'd rather try out DSpace 7, we have public demo sites as well:

- REST API: https://dspace7.4science.it/dspace-spring-rest/
- Angular UI: https://dspace7-demo.atmire.com/

The public demo sites are kept updated as development progresses.